# Zoom out selenium chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a big table and I want the get all columns. The columns start from left and finish to right and when I zoom out more are displayed.

The only way that I was able to make zoom is with:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) RunEnvironment.getWebDriver();
executor.executeScript("document.body.style.zoom = '30%'");
```

The problem with this approach scales the entire page and the elements does not resize.

Eg with stackoverflow with a scale of 0.5:
[image]

While If i zooming using mouse wheel I get:
[image]

All the elements inside page are resized. Is there a way to get the same output with selenium?

I tried also something like:

```
WebElement body = RunEnvironment.getWebDriver().findElement(By.tagName("body"));
body.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"-"));

//or

body.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.SUBTRACT));
```

But doesn't work. The application is created with Angular 8.

Comment: Why do you need to zoom? I am mostly familiar with using selenium for testing or web scraping. In both cases, there is no need to zoom since you can parse the page no matter it's visual size. What are the reasons for zooming for your use case?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I want to get all the elements that have app-table-head-cell-manager tag. If I am doing something like driver.findElements(By.tagName("app-table-head-cell-manager") then I get only the columns from the current view. If I zoom out then I can get more columns in my array, I have added a wait and manually zoomed out and works ok. Do you have here other idea that can solve this issue?\

Comment: What do you mean by "current view"? Does the page scroll horizontally? I've not seen this before and assume that `findElements()` parses the entire page not just the portion that is "visible". My guess is that there is some other reason you are not getting the elements you expect. I think you should post a new question about that issue rather than this proposed solution to the real issue you are trying to solve.

Comment: I think you're dealing with a responsive design. You actually want to set your screen size of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a table, Instead of zooming out, you can scroll to the right most column, which would load all elements into DOM.

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) RunEnvironment.getWebDriver();     
executor.executeScript("document.querySelector('table th:last-child').scrollIntoView();");
```

Comment: I don't htink this works as the data is not in the DOM. From what I can tell by the OP.

Comment: Yes, this didn't work. It's strange because if I zoom out using mouse it's all good but with document.body.style.zoom I don't get the same result. The page is decrease with what I have in the current view washout allowing to the other columns to appear.